# What's the standard way to update a large number of arbitrary rows in MSSQL?

Tags: t-sql, powershell

I have a SQL database table containing configuration for a large number of devices.  I need to update the value of one of the properties (TemplateID) for about 1000 of these devices, based on a spreadsheet from the business side of the company.  In a more mainstream programming language, I'd read the spreadsheet into an array and do a foreach against the array into a where against the dataset.

TSQL doesn't seem to have a foreach function, and I'm not sure how to read in a spreadsheet ... or what data type to use once I read it in.

What's the standard or proper way to do this TSQL?

Comment: A macro in the spreadsheet could handle that.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille there’s an interesting idea that chills my bones.  So is that the standard answer?  Use a different language and make an ODBC connection?

Comment: You are easily frightened.  I never provide standard answers, I aim above that.  Here I merely suggested a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options but there is no “standard” way. Which one you choose will be influenced by your unique situation. I do have a couple of suggestions.

If you’re a whiz at Excel, you can write a formula that builds a T-SQL UPDATE statement from the column values. Copy and paste into SSMS and go. I’d go this route if this task is a one-off.

You can use the Import Data Wizard to read your spreadsheet into a table. From there you can use an UPDATE...FROM statement to modify your configuration table with the spreadsheet values. I’d go this route if it’s somewhat likely this will be a regular thing. Save your work and you have a process that can be completed in just a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I thought that if this could be done with Excel macros, it could surely be done with PowerShell. And yeah, there's a cmdlet for that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this can be done with PowerShell these days, so that's the approach I'll take.  Something like:

```
# Import the data from Excel with PSExcel module.
$KioskstoUpdate = Import-XLSX $ExcelFile;
ForEach ($Device in $KioskstoUpdate)
{
     $SQLQuery = "USE $SQLDatabase UPDATE MyDatabase.TableToChange SET TemplateID ='$TemplateID' WHERE ClientID = '$Device.ClientID'"
     $TemplateID = $KioskstoUpdate.TemplateID -as [int]
     Invoke-SQLcmd -query $SQLQuery -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword
}
```

Comment: I think the `UPDATE` needs a `WHERE`, otherwise it will update all rows of the table in each step of the iteration.

Comment: If ever an alias was more appropriate.